# phpunit test with ::class constant

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Basicly I've got class with use ::class constant from another. For example:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

class example {
   public function fancyMethod($object)
   {
       if(get_class($object) == Foo::class)
       {
        // do some
       } elseif(get_class($object) == Bar::class)
       {
        // somehing else
       }

  }
}
```

now the problem is how to mock during tests object of `Foo` class. The mock `::class` constant would return me something like `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject`

any suggestions?

Comment: if you really wanna do that thing you can use `is_a($object, Foo::class)`

Comment: thought is deprecated, ofcourse I can always also ude "instanceof" but that would change a lot in my code....my bad...

Comment: `is_a` used to be deprecated but is not any more since PHP 5.3. Why would using `is_a` or `instanceof ` lead to many code changes? You have a lot of cases with this manual dispatching or for some other reasons?

Comment: other. actually I used classname as array key ;) nvm. will have to do it. thx. anyway